# Regex Javascript find /replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add a space after every period (full stop). But not if it is a decimal point or an abbreviation.Using javascript I have used the following regex:

```
text.replace(/([^.]*?[a-zA-Z][^.0-9]*?)\.([\S][^.]*?)|([^.]*?[0-9])\.([^\s0-9][^.]*?)/g, "$1. $2")
```

Sample string:

> An apple a day.keeps the doctor away.apple 3.0 is simply
>   amazing.Iphone 5.is not bad either.

Output:

> An apple a day. keeps the doctor away. apple 3.0 is simply amazing. I.
>   s not bad either.

The phone disappears for some weird reason. I used regexpal.com and it is able to find the portions as expected. There is an issue with the replacement.

Also, I would appreciate suggestions for some great find and replace debuggers.

Comment: What's the abbreviation example? Do you mean an acronym?

Comment: How do you intend to tell the difference between the end of a sentence and dot-syntax code (foo.bar) or email addresses (joe.blow@mycompany.com), etc.? Regex won't help you with that.

Comment: adding an url to the test could help

Comment: A nice debugger for Regex is [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: yes, by abbreviation I imply acronym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't escaped the periods, so some characters are being stripped out.  You are also leaving off the `$3` and `$4`.  Since they fully alternate each other, the following should work (and will work with your example):

```
replace(/([^.]?[a-zA-Z][^.0-9]?)\.([\S][^.]?)|([^.]?[0-9])\.([^\s0-9][^.]*?)/g,
    "$1$3. $2$4")
```